# Give an instance only access to tag itself?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

Looking at [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/686526/how-do-you-tag-and-name-the-ec2-instance-that-was-launched-by-an-ec2-spot-reques) this guy used a policy (applied to a role) to let an instance tag itself.

I want EXACTLY the same thing. I could use this policy, but it would be nice if the instance could only tag itself and not other instances.

I can't use ${ec2:SourceInstanceARN} as the resource so I'm trying to use a condition that matches the arn that policy variable evaluates to.

This policy won't validate: (`Syntax errors in policy` )

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:DescribeTags",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ArnEquals": {
                    "ec2:SourceInstanceARN": "${ec2:SourceInstanceARN}"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 7):

For ec2 self-action only policy, you can go off of this. We utilize it for hosts to only be able to self-terminate, self tag, etc.

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "SelfTaggingOnly",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:DeleteTags",
                "ec2:DescribeTags"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:ARN": "${ec2:SourceInstanceARN}"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I wrote a small powershell test validation to confirm. It attempts to self-tag, remove the tag, then attempts to tag a host that exists strictly for validating the attempts of ec2 actions outside the realm of "self". In the output of my validation below, the first run utilizes the policy above, for the second run I removed the condition.

With the above policy in place:

```
Create Tags for self: PASS!
Remove Tags from self: PASS!
Unable to modify another instance's tags: PASS!
You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message: b9KG8BIyxQs~truncated_encoded_output~
```

Removed the condition:

```
Create Tags for self: PASS!
Remove Tags from self: PASS!
Validation falure! I am able to modify other instance's tags!
```

Comment: Did you test the 'red'(FAIL) state before applying the policy? There should be other policy that is allowing you to query the tags, because that condition is not valid.

Comment: This doesn't validate anymore. "aws:ARN" is not accepted.

Comment: aws:ARN still working for me today for CreateTags condition (tho I only tested in GovCloud). It is not documented on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html however, so maybe it will be removed. Strange that specifying `"Resource": "${ec2:SourceInstanceARN}"` in the statement raises an error

Answer (score 5):

You can not limit the `DescribeTags` call to the instance itself using`"ec2:SourceInstanceARN"`:

[image: aws iam policy visual editor showing you can not apply that condition key]

On https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazonec2.html#amazonec2-policy-keys the `DescribeTags` does not show any *Resource* to limit, so I'll bet that you **can not** restrict that API call to any resource.