# Where is aws:ARN condition key defined?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Some time ago I found [Give an instance only access to tag itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40513132/give-an-instance-only-access-to-tag-itself) and the answer of user BMac of using a condition:

```
"Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "aws:ARN": "${ec2:SourceInstanceARN}"
            }
        }
```

The condition worked like a charm, but ever since I have been wondering where is aws:ARN define in aws documentation, but I have not been able to find that condition key anywhere, and google search only link to that stackoverflow post. Can someone please explain where that key comes from, I am afraid I am missing on many more I don't know exists that could make my life easier.

Notes: I search places like https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_actions-resources-contextkeys.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html with no luck

Comment: I don't see `aws:ARN` documented anywhere. Did you also attempt to use `aws:SourceArn` with the ARN operators such as 'ArnEquals'?

Comment: the point is comparing the target's ARN to the originator of the request so that to make sure it is de same, so only allow self actions, but the only way I have found to have the target ARN is with `aws:ARN` that is nowhere on the docs. I imagine comparing `aws:SourceArn` and `SourceInstanceARN` to be mostly pointless as it would be true on most cases, and is not my objective

Comment: Facing the same issue here. aws:ARN just fails validation for me.

Comment: I have spent the last 10 min following the same path as you @JoseDuran. I cannot find it documented anywhere but that other question's answer for using `aws:ARN` for restricting instance tag management to itself is working perfectly for me.

I suspect it was one of the first conditions created and it was quickly deprecated b/c of `SourceArn` and the confusion over what it referred to exactly.

Another weird thing is that specifying `"Resource": "${ec2:SourceInstanceARN}"` in a policy statement does not work.